# How can I update Spring and Hibernate libraries in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: spring, hibernate, netbeans, libraries

Probably, it's a common and obvious issue, but I couldn't find the answer, so, a short tutorial or a link would be appreciated. My NetBeans has been recently updated, but if I create a new project, that uses Spring and Hibernate, the IDE provides options for Spring 3.0.2 (and even 2.5.6) and Hibernate 3.2.5. Of course, I could add manualy all the new libraries for each project, but it doesn't seem like a good idea. Just in case it's important, I use Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not use a build tool with dependency management (maven, gradle builder)? That way you can make the build tool do the dependency management, but it still works fine in an IDE.

Comment: @ebaxt this might answer your question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137329/convince-a-lone-developer-to-use-a-separate-build-tool-instead-of-the-ide-one-cl

Comment: Thanks, you both are hundred percent right. I had already face a few troubles where configured pom.xml would help a lot. The only reason I didn't choose that option is that I hadn't yet read a book on maven.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use a build tool just for the build tool just for the sake of it, but things like upgrading dependencies, and handling transitive dependencies makes it worth the effort. Also, with tools like maven/gradel that comes with artifacts and that favors conventions over configuration, the startup cost/time is basically 5-10 minutes to get you going. From there on you can use the IDE as you already are using it, and gradually learn the build tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've found a way to do that. In NetBeans's menu Tools/Libraries there are options for creating new libraries and adding its jar files or folders. I tried to add new Spring libraries (I didn't have a chance to [put spaces in its name](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46863)) and they appeared as an option of Spring MVC version when creating a new project.